# Expectation of minimum and maximum of sum of iid random variables?

Tags: probability, summation, expectation

Looking for $\mathrm{E}[\min(\sum{X}) ]$ and $\mathrm{E}[\max(\sum{X})]$.
Paper references much appreciated.

Model: let's say we have 3 connected devices in a signal processing pipeline:

$$
\underset{\mu,\sigma,\min,\max}{\text{sampler}}
\rightarrow (X)\rightarrow 
\underset{\text{over }k}{\text{summator}}
\rightarrow(Y)\rightarrow
\underset{\text{over }m}{\text{extremer}}
\rightarrow(Z^\min,Z^\max)\rightarrow
$$

1) **sampler** is producing random signal series $X_{t1}$ 
with period $T_X=1$, and $X$ has stable distribution, 
with known mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, minimum $\min$, maximum $\max$.

2) **summator** is looking at $X$ and producing series $Y_{t2}=\sum{X}_{n}$ 
with period $T_Y=k*T_X=k$, $k>1$, creating new sum 
over every bucket of $k$ samples of $X$.

3) **extremer** is looking for $Y$ boundaries and 
producing 2 series $Z^\min_{t3}=\min(Y_n)$ and $Z^\max_{t3}=\max(Y_n)$,
with period $T_Z=m*T_Y=m*k$, $m>1$, creating new minimum and maximum 
over every bucket of $m$ samples of $Y$.

How one obtains expectations $E_\min=\mathrm{E}[Z^\min]$ 
and $E_\max=\mathrm{E}[Z^\max]$ based on 
known parameters $X$ $(\mu,\sigma,\min,\max)$
and frequency parameters $(k,m)$?

**NOTE**:
Current answer does not take into account $\min$ and $\max$ assumption.
Probably an approach similar to [Irwin–Hall distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) calculation
would give a better estimate. What do you think?

Comment: The minimum taken over what? All natural numbers?

Comment: Over bounded sequence with bound distribution with known mean, variance, minimum and maximum.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question. You have a specified sequence of iid random variables $X_n$, that's fine. What is $\min \sum_n X_n$? Is it $\min_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{n=1}^m X_n$?

Comment: Yes, finite **m**.

Comment: Please see if question makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks pretty hard to derive a closed expression for this. What I might do if I had to have an answer is assume k is big, apply the Central Limit Theorem to the sum, and then use the approximation discussed here to yank an order statistic from it:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/approximate-order-statistics-for-normal-random-variables

Some references are cited in that discussion

Comment: Thanks. Sorry can not up-vote yet. Do you know if closed forms exist with some kinds of "normality" assumptions?

Comment: The paper by Roysten in the link gives an exact formula for a normal distribution, but I'm willing to bet he wrote the paper because an approximation is worth working with. And if your Xs are distributed normally to begin with, you don't have to worry about k being "big enough", the formula Roysten gives would be exact, if that's where you're going with the question.

Comment: Yes, AS-177 is a real gem, thank you. I'll wait a bit longer to see if other good math people offer any other insight for this problem.